# The best web hosting option to start off on

Tags: web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm extremely new to hosting, and i've just finished developing a site for my friend. If you were to select a web host with great support and affordable price, which one would it be?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Piers on Dreamhost. Their shared hosting gives you features you wouldn't get elsewhere (SSH access, mod_pagespeed, MySQL domains, etc). And if you find the right coupon code, you end up paying less then 50 bucks a year.

Moving forward, look for a host that offers both shared hosting and VPS/dedicated hosting if you use it for work. You never know when you might need to use a better machine to run your site.

Comment: DreamHost is also nice as they give you a significant amount of configurability for a shared hosting service. You can even compile your own PHP binaries with your own extensions. So if there's a PHP extension they won't install for you, you can always install it yourself, which is also good practice for managing your own server. The only downside for me is their lack of PostgreSQL support.

Comment: Yeah, no PostgreSQL is a bummer, but with how often they add new features (mod_pagespeed added within a day of it's release) it's not inconceivable that they'd add it sometime soon.

Comment: You'd think so, but pgSQL's been on the user wishlist for like 6 years: https://panel.dreamhost.com/index.cgi?tree=home.sugg&category=_all&search=Offer%20the%20PostgreSQL (vote for it if you've got a DH account and want to see pgSQL added.)

Comment: Not to mention Dreamhost starts you off with SVN already set up.

Answer (score 2):

I would also vote Dreamhost (http://dreamhost.com), quite a value with a promocode (yeah, you could use folktrash), a kinda expensive registrar, but you get one free registration with a hosting plan, and their support is excellent.

They've had some growing pains this past year, but I've been a client for over ten and am breaking on through to the other side with them.

Oh, and I've had nothing but terrible experiences with godaddy.

Comment: Their domains are only $9.95, which should be about on par with the industry average. The only thing I don't like is the $100 redemption fee for reclaiming an expired domain (otherwise you gotta compete with the domain squatters/resellers). It's the same with basically all other registrars though--some are even more expensive.

Comment: As a user and a lover of all things Dreamhost, the only bad thing I can say about them is that, statistically of course, they have a slightly lower uptime percentage of other hosts. We're talking like .3% here, but a number is a number and it does happen. That said, if you're using them for a personal site that isn't always mission critical, you won't really mind.

Answer (score 1):

Shared hosting is probably the way forward. Something like what Dreamhost does.

Have a look around to find something that both fits your budget but also look at reviews. Just remember that you get what you pay for, so don't be fooled by companies offering free web hosting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Hostgator.com  (it has good reputation)

Answer (score 0):

I like godaddy.com

- Straight forward pricing
- online tools to manage all your site needs
- great support, just call, they help

Comment: I've had nothing but nightmares with Godaddy.